# Is there a way to compare the stored values and the inputs by user to remove duplicates in django views?

Tags: python, django

I have a variable in Django View which is `interfacelist` and it contains `[TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1, TenGigabitEthernet1/0/2, TenGigabitEthernet1/0/20, TenGigabitEthernet1/0/21]`. This is what the user input from the HTML and I `request.POST.get` it to the view. And in my database (SQL), I have the following:

[image]

Here comes the question, how do i compare the data in the database and `interfacelist` and remove any duplicates? Like in this case, `TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1, TenGigabitEthernet1/0/2` so I would remove it and keep the `TenGigabitEthernet1/0/20, TenGigabitEthernet1/0/21` to be updated in the database.

I tried the following codes: (This is happening is Django View)

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT interface FROM {tablename} WHERE id >=2")
righttable = cursor.fetchall()
print(righttable)
#Notworking
#for i in righttable:
#    if interfacelist[i] == righttable[i]:
#            interfacelist.remove(a)
#Notworking            
for i in interfacelist:
updatequery2 = f"INSERT INTO {tablename}(interface) VALUES('{i}')"
cursor.execute(updatequery2)
cursor.close()
```

The variable `righttable` in this case will be the image shown earlier. It contains `[TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1,TenGigabitEthernet1/0/2,TenGigabitEthernet1/0/3,TenGigabitEthernet1/0/4,TenGigabitEthernet1/0/5]`. Also, the commented out codes are not working as it gives me a error of `list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`. So in this situation, the outcome I want it is to be for the `interfacelist` to only have `TenGigabitEthernet1/0/20, TenGigabitEthernet1/0/21` and update the database. Which means `TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1, TenGigabitEthernet1/0/2` are `.remove` as the database contains it already. How do I fix this to achieve what I wanted? Would greatly appreciate if anyone can advise or help me. Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying that you want 1/0/20 and 1/0/21 to replace 1/0/2? i.e. if there is an existing interface that is a prefix of the ones you're inserting, remove them?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. So in this case, in the interfacelist, i want to remove 1/0/1 and 1/0/2 as the database contains both 1/0/1 and 1/0/2 already

Comment: Your not working code is because `righttable` is a sequence of tuples, which means `i` is a tuple. So you're effectively doing something like `interfacelist[(1, "G0/1", "1.1.1.1")]`

Comment: My ```righttable``` is printing the following ```[('TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1,'), ('TenGigabitEthernet1/0/2',), ('TenGigabitEthernet1/0/3',),('TenGigabitEthernet1/0/4',),('TenGigabitEthernet1/0/5',)]``` though. In this case, may I ask how would you correct the code to achieve the outcome I want?

Comment: **Note**: The way you write queries you are **vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**! Please read through the documentation on [Performing raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/), specifically see the section "Passing parameters into raw()" and later.